# Adding links to specific phrases or keywords in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to turn specific words or phrases into links with jQuery.  So far I have only been successful in changing a span with a class="link" to an anchor tag after a hover event.   My problem is that I want them to change when the page loads.  As an added benefit it would be nice to target any words or phrases without having to put them in spans.

```
$('span.link').hover(function () {

    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='http://mydomain.com'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>");

});
```

Works only when they hover over the text, but what I really want is something like this:

```
var keyword = 'my keyword';

var link = $(document).find(keyword);

$(document).ready(function() {
    link.replaceWith("<a href='http://mydomain.com'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>");
 });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583303/search-for-words-replace-with-links/1583582#1583582.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the hover event to initiate the change, use the each method which will execute for each matched element the moment you call it ..

so

```
$('span.link').each(function () {

    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='http://mydomain.com'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>");

});
```

will convert all yours spans to links in one go ..